# Can I perform queries in django pre_save signals?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

This is models.py

```
class ledger1(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Company = models.ForeignKey(company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='Companys')
    Creation_Date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32,unique=True)
    Opening_Balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2)
    Closing_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)


class journal(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Company = models.ForeignKey(company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='Companyname')
    Date = models.DateField()
    By = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
    To = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
    Debit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,)
    Credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
```

I want to make a mathamatical equation using django queries and the result of my equation will be displayed in the ledger1.Closing_Balance field

So I have tried this:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=ledger1)
def update_user_closing_balance(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    Closing_balance = ledger1.objects.annotate(debitsum=Sum('Debitledgers__Debit')) + instance.Opening_Balance - ledger1.objects.annotate(creditsum=Sum('Creditledgers__Credit'))
    instance.Closing_balance = Closing_balance
```

Is it possible in django???
Because if I run this I am getting unsupported operand error...

Is there any alternative code for this???

If anyone knows it...Plz help

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unsupported operand exception has nothing to do with the query itself, but with the expression you wrote:

```
Closing_balance = (
   ledger1.objects.annotate(debitsum=Sum('Debitledgers__Debit')) +
   instance.Opening_Balance -
   ledger1.objects.annotate(creditsum=Sum('Creditledgers__Credit'))
)
```

so here you are adding `QuerySet`s together with real values, and that does not make any sense. What you probably wanted to use was an `.aggregate(..)`, and then wrap the value it contains out of it, like:

```
debitsum = ledger1.objects.aggregate(debitsum=Sum('Debitledgers__Debit'))['debitsum']
creditsum = ledger1.objects.aggregate(creditsum=Sum('Creditledgers__Credit'))['creditsum']

Closing_balance = debitsum + instance.Opening_Balance - creditsum
```

But that being said, using signals to pre-calculate aggregates is typically *not* a good idea. Since for example a `journal` object can change its `Debit` or `Credit` value, and this will not "fire" the signal, hence no update is done. Even if you also add logic for such events, it can still happen that the signals do not fire, since for example updating in bulk will surpass the signaling system.

Usually it is better *not* to store data aggregates, since this leads to [*data duplication*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb245678.aspx) which, like the article says "*breeds redundancy and inconsistency.*". If you want to calculate such aggregates, it might be better to use a (materialized) view at the database level.

**EDIT**: the query itself however does not seem to make any sense. If you update a `ledger` record, you can perform a filtering, and calculate the update that way:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=ledger1)
def update_user_closing_balance(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    debit = instance.Debitledgers.aggregate(debit=Sum('Debit'))['debit']
    credit = instance.Creditledgers.aggregate(credit=Sum('Credit'))['credit']
    instance.Closing_balance = instance.Opening_Balance + debit - credit
```

But this probably will still not suffice, since you will then need to do some proper filtering on the date, etc.

Comment: No actually I want diffrent closing balances for diffrent ledgers...If I use aggregate It will be same for all ledgers...Is there any possibilities to perform this?

Comment: @NiladryKar: say that are different `ledger`s, then how are you supposed to save it an **`instance`**? A `pre_save`, and `post_save` always works on *one* instance.

Comment: Oooo yes totally forgot that..Can you provide me another way to perform this???@Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @NiladryKar: well somehow you always end up with the **XY** problem, instead of explaining *how* you want to solve something, try to explain *what* you want to solve.

Comment: @NiladryKar: the following *might* do the trick, but as said in the article, this is simply an anti-pattern. Data duplication has resulted huge software disasters (like explained in the article). So it is simply not a good idea to introduce such data duplication (yourself).

Comment: Thank you very much@Willem Van Onsem...Yeah I know that this is just half completed...Very much thanks to you for providing this to me this is just what I was looking for...

Comment: I have 1 more doubt if you can clear it for me...What will I change in the receiver function If I change the sender to journal???